# Lost volume on external 4TB drive by converting from GPT to MBR

Tags: hard-drive, mbr, gpt

I am fully aware that i acted like a complete fool.

Situation:

I have Seagate M3 4TB external drive has one volume sized 4TB and containing 300GB of data. I converted it from GPT to MBR. The result is obvious: i cannot access the data anymore since Windows 10 shows it only to be a basic disk (online) with one 2048 GB unallocated and another 1678 GB unallocated.

I know the data is still there but logically inaccessible by now.

Questions: can I simply switch back to GPT? Will the volume be accessible again then? If not, what should I do exactly then?

I am running only Windows 10 or 7 machines, external hdd is plugged in via USB 2.0 (3.0 available too).

Disk Management showing Disk 1 what it is looking like now

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you converted from GPT to MBR?  Hopefully, you have a backup of your data, because your actions were extremely destructive to your chances of data recovery

Comment: I wanted to clone this hdd to another one. The software (Acronis Disk Director) said something like "cloning only MBR disks" (clone was greyed out) I followed their hint to convert either the disk containing the data and the empty disk to mbr. Like i said, i know it was a foolish thing to do. I kind of relied on the previously bought [Acronis DD](https://www.acronis.com/en-us/personal/disk-manager/) which didn't say something like "you are at risk losing your data".

Comment: If you booted Acronis Disk Director while in legacy mode, that would explain the reason, it had no idea what to do with a GPT disk.

Comment: @Ramhound Why couldn't ADD have an idea of what to do with a GPT disk when booted in legacy mode? GPT is not tied to UEFI in any way, it is just a partitioning scheme. I think it was really irresponsible of Acronis to suggest converting the disk to MBR, as they should know the maximum size of a an MBR disk is 2 TB.

Comment: @JohanMyréen - I have used Acronis products for years, if you were using their WinRE bootable disk, the limitations of MBR with regards to Windows is well known.  I also don't know what the message said exactly, so I am not willing to, extrapolate what actually happen.

Comment: If the data on the disk is valuable, you could invest some time (or money, by letting someone else do it) to try to reconstruct the partition table. By examining the disk sector by sector, you could figure out where the first block of the file system is stored, which would also be the start of the partition. If you are lucky, the conversion tool has left the backup copy of the GPT partition table at the end of the disk intact. Using a suitable tool you could restore the main table from the backup.

Comment: If you're able to use a Linux live environment, then recovery could be trivial - potentially without even requiring somewhere to place the data in the meantime. If you're limited to Windows then (in my experience) your chances are dramatically reduced.

Comment: ... in the meantime, don't do _anything_ with the disk - unplug and power down.

Comment: I would suggest connecting the disk to a Linux machine and immediately backing up every single byte of the disk using `dd`. That way, you can attempt recovery as many times in as many ways as you need to.

Comment: ok, thanks to all replies, honestly! As now now, I yesterday bought a copy of Active@ Partition Recovery and am [restoring](https://imgur.com/a/uEDKeSg) from that questionable disk to another one of same kind (Seagate M3 4TB USB). It currently is running around 20h and has done 30%. I thought to myself "I need to do something what does not perform any write operations on this disk." I hope that restore does only _read_